# Where can I find a list of commonly mistaken characters?

Tags: characters, character-identification, academic, mistakes

I want to quickly identify potential mistakes created by OCR software. Where can I find a list of all Chinese characters that visually look very similar and might often be confused?

Comment: I doubt such a reference exists as there are plenty of characters that only differ by a few strokes. Just curious as to why you would need such a list?

Comment: Wiktionary: [Appendix:Easily confused Chinese characters](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Easily_confused_Chinese_characters).

Answer (score 9):

A friend and I have started to collect a list of characters easy to misread by language learners: http://code.google.com/p/eclectus/source/browse/trunk/libeclectus/data/similarcharacters.csv

Answer (score 5):

[List of 236 sets of commonly confused characters](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/scripts/similarchars.htm) on Cantodict.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of anything exactly like that, but you can find characters with similar structure at [zhongwen.com](http://zhongwen.com/), and you can see the structural decomposition of characters at [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons%3aChinese_characters_decomposition).

Answer (score 3):

I started a web site to collect and help differentiate similar-looking Chinese characters: [HorizontalHanzi.com](http://horizontalhanzi.com)

You can either search for a character to view a list of similar ones (e.g. search for 主 and get 王, 玉, 壬) or just browse the database.

Lists show the characters placed side-by-side for easy comparison as well as definition breakdowns and links to sites with more details about the individual characters.

Contributions welcome!

Comment: Not sure why this would get down-voted when it's entirely relevant and non-commercial...

Comment: I'm leaving your answer here to improve on. It's OK to have a link to your own site, however your answer doesn't explain how your site answers the question. Regardless of the question we don't accept answers which are just "follow this link". Otherwise at a glance it just looks like an advertisement, if you can explain how your site helps to answer this question that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

My list of similar characters.
https://kmccready.wordpress.com/2019/01/18/my-list-of-similar-chinese-characters/

Answer (score 0):

I have a list of 1200+ characters that are easily confused, its hardly comprehensive but its certainly a start.

[My list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qn8Nsbg8UY_bKIYhZ3tEnWkjd4gjkQWnfBRxvI7TJIk/edit?usp=sharing)